# Draw circle and scale box in android

Tags: android, android-canvas

[Display image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gO07.jpg)

In my application, i want to draw some geometrical shapes like circle, rectangle. When i drag, the circle should be drawn as shown in the image. When i select the circle, i should be able to move and resize circle. See the image for my requirement. Now i am only able to draw circle. How to get that scaling box around the circle? Help me with this.

@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

```
    boolean handled = false;
    int pointerId;
    int actionIndex = event.getActionIndex();

    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            clearCirclePointer();

            mStartX = (int) event.getX();
            mStartY = (int) event.getY();
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            pointerId = event.getPointerId(actionIndex);

            mMidPointX = (int) ((event.getX() + mStartX) / 2);
            mMidPointY = (int) ((event.getY() + mStartY) / 2);

            mRadius = (int) Math.sqrt((Math.pow(mMidPointX - mStartX, 2) + Math.pow(mMidPointY - mStartY, 2)));

            mPaint.setPathEffect(dashPath);

            invalidate();

            handled = true;

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            mEndX = (int) event.getX();
            mEndY = (int) event.getY();

            mMidPointX = ((mEndX + mStartX) / 2);
            mMidPointY = ((mEndY + mStartY) / 2);

            mRadius = (int) Math.sqrt((Math.pow(mMidPointX - mStartX, 2) + Math.pow(mMidPointY - mStartY, 2)));

            mPaint.setPathEffect(solidPath);

            mCircle.setxAxis(mMidPointX);
            mCircle.setyAxis(mMidPointY);
            mCircle.setRadius(mRadius);
            mCircle.setPaint(mPaint);

            mCirclePointer.put(event.getPointerId(0), mCircle);

            invalidate();

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:

            handled = true;

            break;

        default:

            break;
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event) || handled;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    super.onDraw(canvas);

     for (Circle circle : mCircleSet) {

         if (mCircleSet == null || mCircleSet.size() == 0)
             return;

        canvas.drawCircle(circle.getxAxis(), circle.getyAxis(), circle.getRadius(), circle.getPaint());
    }
}
```